# Testing a difficult to reach code path

Tags: c#

Whenever I want to exercise a certain path of code that would otherwise only be reached under a difficult to reproduce `condition` like:

```
if (condition) { code to be tested }
```

I `or` it with a `true` value:

```
if (true || condition) { code to be tested }
```

Is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: Are you trying to run the code through the debugger? I would advise looking into `unit testing` this. A mocking solution may help making your code testable. By writing it as a unit test you not only get to test your code now, but you get to keep the test as well!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think more *`elegant way`* is using **`the logical negation operator (!)`** as;

```
if (!condition) { code to be tested }
```

***But more safe way for debugging or testing purposes*** you can use a ***preprocessor directive*** (as per my commet). When you finish testing simply remove or change `#define UnreachableTest`

```
#define UnreachableTest //should be on the top of the class/page

#if (UnreachableTest) 
    condition = !condition; //or
    condition = true;
#endif

if (condition) { code to be tested }
```

Comment: Yes it looks to me more elegant. With the only catch that it would not work when the condition is met. But I like it and I guess it would be good in most use cases.

Comment: In that case you can use a `preprocessor directive` to change the condition for testing purpose during the debug. As; `#define UnreachableTest` on top... `#if (UnreachableTest) condition = !condition #endif` Then your actual code to follow.

Comment: Sorry I have to give a -1 on this answer. This is a very bad code smell to change the logical condition to do testing. It's dangerous as it could lead to someone forgetting to remove that "!" and end up with production code having the condition flipped and creating errors/bugs.

Comment: @AlanBarber: Did you read the OP? he is looking for the best elegant way and already accepted as the answer. Also you have to read my first comment how to make it more practical.

Comment: @Kaf yes, I'm pointing out the danger of tossing a "!" into a condition. The preprocessor directive is a much more elegant and safer solution and I gave you a +1 on that comment.

Comment: I agree with Alan. That *looks like real code*, which means when you're doing a sweep before releasing to production, you're unlikely to notice it. At which point you're cleaning up the shattered mess of *only* corrupt data having reached your system for 12 hours before anyone noticed. Do it 500 times, across 30 different files, and World of Pain results. At least if (true || ...) can be searched for.

Comment: @AlanBarber: I had mentioned it in my comments. I have edited the answer now.

Comment: @deworde : As I said to Alen, I had mentioned how to make it more practical/safe in my comments. I have added my comments to the answer now.

Comment: Fair enough. One other question: any reason not to just make condition = true instead of condition = !condition?

Comment: @deworde: Well, if it is true it will run regardless of the condition (which is more like removing the condition). If it is !condition it will run for difficult to make sort of...

Comment: @Kaf +1 for the nice answer :)

Answer (score 13):

More elegant solution is using mocks. Make decisions based on dependencies or parameters:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.IsBar).Returns(true);
var sut = new Sut(mock.Object);
sut.DoSomething();
```

And in your system under test:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    if (_foo.IsBar)
        // code path to test
}
```

Comment: read question before posting - `want to exercise a certain path of code that would otherwise only be reached under a difficult to reproduce condition`  OP goal is to test the code inside `if`, ie go there with 100% chance

Comment: @Nogard I mentioned usage of mocks. And added code sample. Read answer to the end before commenting.

Comment: Sure I saw that, but your pre-edited answer (which I commented)stated only `difficult to reproduce condition` - mocking as well could use it. Then Mock sample was added and it solves OP issue.

Comment: @Nogard I upped your last comment but I have issue with the _solves OP issue_ part. Although this answer is solid advice (after amended), it is more than what was asked.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the first line of code (`if (condition)...`). Is that sarcasm?

Comment: @Clodoaldo I'll remove that - just don't use constant values in if conditions `if (true)` etc. In this case you can remove condition, because it does not affect code execution path

Answer (score 3):

Your approach, with "true or", and the approach of if (!condition) are the simplest.  Here is an approach that I like for large programs

Create a function, let's call it testme(const string).  And instead of inserting true in if test, you insert testme, with some string that identifies that piece of code.

```
    if ( testme("Location 123") || condition ) { code to be tested }
```

Then, using some kind of config file, or arguments to your program (i prefer config), you can totally control when testme("Location 123") will return true.  AND you can use the same function in many locations.  Just change the config file to test each one.

Comment: +1. I have been using a boolean variable defined somewhere else for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume this is not a unit test scenario since it wasn't mentioned in the question.  By far the simplest way to do on-the-fly testing of code like this is by using the debugger's Set Next Statement command.

Set a breakpoint on the if() statement, if necessary, or step the code until it reaches that statement.  Then right-click the next line, inside the if() statement body, and select "Set Next Statement".  Code will resume executing at that line, completely skipping the if().

Comment: Good +1. I will sure use it. But in this specific case where I want to run that path at least a few times it is awkward.

Answer (score 2):

Put the code to be tested in a separate method. Then you can call the method and bypass the conditional. Now you won't have to worry about adding "true" or more importantly forgetting to remove it.

You can also add unit tests for the method so that you can modify the parameters passed into it and test all the scenarios you want.